# ssh - connection refused

Tags: linux, ssh

I have server on ovh.org.
Since yesterday I can't login by ssh, I only have access to my server by ssh and my id_rsa.pub.

How I can in anothery way connect to my server, and what I do on future in similar case?
Restart of server not helping, but all services working on docker.

Comment: You can or you can't login?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.